# convert date time in a specific format to timestamp android

Tags: android, timestamp

I want to convert two dates in this form ie...18-10-2019 01:05 pm into a timestamp and then compare them. I have tried this but it's not working

```
public void getTimeStamp(){

  try{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy K:mm aa");
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("10-18-2019 01:05 pm");
    Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
    Log.d("***parsedDate",parsedDate.toString());
    Log.d("***timestamp",timestamp.toString());
  } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  } 

}
```

Please help me

Comment: What's the issue in this ?

Comment: it shows the timestamp in date and time format and not in digits as it should

Comment: It will be in long format not in TimeStamp so take accordingly

Comment: it is not even long.it is a string

Comment: something like this 2019-10-18 08:15:00.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, your are using "MM-dd-yyyy K:mm aa" pattern, that mean the first value is the month. But it the parse value, "18" is the month and it's not a valid month. I think you should change the pattern to "dd-MM-yyyy K:mm aa".

And it's better to use Calendar to get the timestamp:

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy K:mm aa");
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("10-18-2019 01:05 pm");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(parsedDate);
        long timestamp = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    } catch (Exception: e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: even after using correct value it is not working.it shows the timestamp in date and time format and not in digits as it should

Comment: You can use `Calendar.timeInMilis` to get timestamp of a date. Check my update for sample code

Comment: .time and .timeInMillis are both in red

Comment: Which Calendar are you importing? You should use `java.util.Calendar` instead of `android.icu.util.Calendar`

Comment: i am using Java.Util.Calendar only

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to use `getTime()` and `getTimeInMillis()`. I'm using Kotlin so that I don't need to call getter/setter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void getTimeStamp(){

    try{

         DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy K:mm aa");
         DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
         Date parsedDate = inputFormat.parse("18-10-2019 01:05 pm");
         String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(parsedDate);
         Log.d("***parsedDate",parsedDate.toString());
         Log.d("***timestamp",outputDateStr);

    } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getTimeStamp(){

  try{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy K:mm aa");
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("10-18-2019 01:05 pm");
    Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
    Log.d("***parsedDate",parsedDate.toString());
    Log.d("***timestamp",timestamp.toString());
  } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  } 


 Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());


Do not cast it to Timestamp take long

Long timestamp = parsedDate.getTime();
```